# Buy X Get Y Free With auto add the same product in the cart

Tags: magento2, discount, promotions

How to implement the custom functionality without extension i.e Buy X Get Y free. If customer buy the 2(X) quantity then the third (Y) will free and the third product will automatically add in the cart with the amount zero(Free product)

If the free extension are available for this( Buy X Get Y free) please share the link.

Am using magento 2.2.2

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for exactly. There are some built in functionality under marketing->car price rules in action area. But if you are looking for something more advanced you can use Amasty module
https://amasty.com/free-gift-for-magento-2.html

Comment: suppose the offer is Buy 1 get 1 free.

Comment: suppose the offer is Buy 1 get 1 free. If the customer purchase the 1 product i.e (xyz) product name and then he/she will get the 1 free product (that free product will auto add the same product in the cart) like this. https://prnt.sc/kry1se